# Dropbox is trying to sync more than is in the folder? Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, sync, dropbox, cloud-storage

```
Dropbox v3.18.1
OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite)
```

**I have `2.54 GB` in my `Dropbox` folder on my `Mac`.** [image]

but my **`DropBox` app keeps syncing** for some reason `(over 3 GB)` and it's out of space `:(`

[image]

This is really really frustrating because I'm basically using DropBox as my `anaconda` Python directory so I can sync it with my work computer.

**What is the extra data it is syncing? Why won't it stop? It's using all of my space. PLEASE HELP!**

Here's my files:

```
Joshs-Air:Dropbox Mu$ ls -altrh
total 728
-rw-r--r--@  1 Mu  staff   329B Apr 18 20:14 py2_bashprofile.backup
-rw-r--r--@  1 Mu  staff    36B Apr 28 11:18 .dropbox
drwxr-xr-x@ 21 Mu  staff   714B Apr 28 14:49 anaconda
drwxr-xr-x+ 86 Mu  staff   2.9K Apr 29 12:14 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 Mu  staff     0B Apr 29 12:14 Icon?
drwxr-xr-x   5 Mu  staff   170B Apr 29 12:14 .dropbox.cache
drwx------@  8 Mu  staff   272B Apr 29 12:14 .
-rw-r--r--@  1 Mu  staff   6.0K Apr 29 14:37 .DS_Store


Joshs-MacBook-Air:Dropbox Mu$ du -sch .[!.]* * 
8.0K    .DS_Store
4.0K    .dropbox
8.0K    .dropbox.cache
348K    Icon
1.3G    anaconda
4.0K    py2_bashprofile.backup
1.3G    total
```

Comment: Do you have any hidden directories or files?

Comment: There's probably some hidden directories in the DropBox folder but shouldn't those be included when I check the file size?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the OSX gui file manager but on the command line you usually need to specify the inclusion of hidden files i.e. `ls -a` or `du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h`. I do know that the file manager requires that you check an option to display hidden files. Perhaps check that if you haven't and see if the total directory size changes.

Comment: Do you have aliases or hard links in there? Maybe it's trying to upload each separately?

Comment: Please provide the output of the `du` command line torchhound suggested, too. `du` is a command line disk usage analyzer, it won’t harm your system.

Comment: @DanielB hey thanks for your response. the output for `du` is much much too long since all of my frameworks for `python3` and `modules` are stored within it. is there something in particular you are looking for that i can maybe `grep`?

Comment: The **command line suggested** just prints one line per top level item (ie. things in `pwd`), though? Also, `sort` on OS X doesn’t support `-h`, so just remove the `|sort -h` part.

Comment: @DanielB I just added the output in the question